# Copy file from SharePoint 2013 to online using on-premises data gateway in power automate

Tags: migration

I need to copy files along with folders from SharePoint 201 to online. For this, created a on-premises data gateway connection.
Used "Get files (properties only)" action in power automate (with the connection of on-premise SharePoint site. Site address and library are given). Then used "Apply to each" action to loop through files and folders. In this action "items('Apply_to_each')?['{Path}']" is empty.
Hence unable to get the file content and create file under the folder path. Need to maintain the folder structure.

Suggestions please!

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the SharePoint Migration Tool instead. This tool is designed for migrating content from on-premises SharePoint to SharePoint Online and may be better suited to your requirements.

[Overview of the SharePoint Migration Tool (SPMT)](https://learn.microsoft.com/sharepointmigration/introducing-the-sharepoint-migration-tool)

Comment: Thankyou for the reply.

This have some limitations and did not migrate all files.

Comment: Which limitations? what type of files? Using proper migration software is the best practice for moving content from on-premises SharePoint to SharePoint Online.